# How to route traffic from multiple servers to external API via single IP?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, port, portforwarding, socat

I need to fetch data from external API, which has white-listed IP requirement i.e. API will respond only to white-listed IPs

I have multiple servers in AWS Autoscaling group that needs to fetch data from this external API. I intend to route these request via servers running on white-listed IP (AWS Elastic IPs).

I am trying to use socat:
`socat -v TCP-LISTEN:80,reuseaddr,fork,su=nobody TCP:api.external-service.com:80`. But getting **Invalid URL** error.

Is socat the right way to solve this problem? if so then how do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a Squid proxy server on the machine with the white-listed IP and route all requests through the proxy.

http://www.squid-cache.org/